# Array in class not storing retrieved values from txt in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, matrix

I have constructed a class for matrix in C++ and I'm not able to retrieve the values from a matrix stored in a txt file. This is the matrix format I'm working with:

```
4 4
3.14 1.59 2.65 3.58
9.79 3.23 8.46 2.64
3.38 3.27 9.50 2.88
4.19 7.16 9.39 9.37
```

The first line is rows and cols, respectively. My header file `Matrix.h` looks like this

```
#ifndef __MATRIX__CLASS__TYPE
#define __MATRIX__CLASS__TYPE

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdlib.h>

class Matrix
{
private:
    unsigned nRows;
    unsigned nCols;
    double **mArray;


public:
    // Create a matrix based on a txt file
    Matrix(const char *);
    // Destructor
    ~Matrix();        

    // Accessing to the Matrix data
    unsigned getRows() const;
    unsigned getCols() const;
    double** getArray() const;
    void printArray() const;

};
#include "matrix.cpp"
#endif
```

My `matrix.cpp` file looks like this:

```
// Constructor for the
Matrix::Matrix(const char *fileName)
{
    // Start by opening the .txt where the matrix is stored
    std::ifstream fileArray(fileName);
    std::string lineFile;
    double cellValue;
    // Set the counter for indexing the array
    unsigned i = 0;
    unsigned j = 0;
    int rows, cols;

    if (fileArray.is_open() && fileArray.good())
    {
        while (getline(fileArray, lineFile))
        {
            // std::cout << lineFile << std::endl;
            std::stringstream streamArray(lineFile);
            j = 0;
            while (1)
            {
                streamArray >> cellValue;
                
                if (!streamArray)
                    break;

                // Retrieve meta data
                if (i == 0 && j == 0)
                {
                    rows = (int) cellValue;
                    nRows = rows;
                    // Initialize the array given the row values were already retrieved
                    mArray = new double *[rows];
                    j += 1;
                    
                }
                else if (i == 0 && j == 1)
                {
                    cols = (int) cellValue;
                    nCols = cols;
                    j += 1;
                }
                else if (cols > 0)
                {
                    // Fill values
                    mArray[i - 1] = new double[cols];
                    mArray[i-1][j] = cellValue;
                    j += 1;
                }
                
            }
            i += 1;
        }
    }
    // Close file
    fileArray.close();
}

// Getter for matrix rows
unsigned Matrix::getRows() const
{
    return this->nRows;
}

// Getter for matrix cols
unsigned Matrix::getCols() const
{
    return this->nCols;
}

// Getter for the array entrys

double **Matrix::getArray() const
{
    return this->mArray;
}

void Matrix::printArray() const
{
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < nRows; i++)
    {
        for (unsigned j = 0; j < nCols; j++)
        {
            std::cout << mArray[i][j] << "\t";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}
```

When I check for the values in `mArray[i-1][j]` individually while I'm still in the loop, it looks like it successfully stored the data in the variable. However, once I print the array using the prin method (`printArray()`) it returns the default values for creating a double-type array and only the last column is modified as I show in the following example:

```
1.27553e-311    1.27553e-311    0       3.58
1.27553e-311    1.27553e-311    8.99755e-91     2.64
0       0       0       2.88
0       0       0       9.37
```

Comment: Use `std::vector` instead of built in arrays.

Comment: when this condition is met `else if (cols > 0)` then `cols` is not initialized. It is only assigned some value when one of the previous conditions is `true`

Comment: Identifiers containing double underscores (anywhere), or beginning with an underscore and a capital letter, are reserved to the implementation for any purpose. `__MATRIX__CLASS__TYPE` risks tripping your code up. Tangential, but I recommend using include guards that don't risk nasal demons.

Comment: oh well, on the first iterations `cols` is initialized I guess.

Comment: it is rather confusing that there are 3 variables for rows in the constructor and the meaning of each is not that clear `rows`, `nrows` and `i`. same for cols

Comment: Search the internet for "C++ FAQ matrix".

Comment: The class declaration has a few ideas ranging from dubious to terrible. `double **mArray;,` is pretty bad, for more than one reason. `Matrix(const char *);` is dubious (you should have an input function (not a c'tor) that takes an istream (not a filename) and then overload operator<< based on that). Likewise the print function should take an ostream. `double** getArray() const;` is just horrible. You return modifiable (!!!) internal representation (!!!) from a const function. You get fired for such things.

Comment: (1) Why do you allocate an array for an entire **row** for every single **field** (and leak the previous row array each time)? Maybe start by fixing this obvious mistake. (2) Where are your `delete[]` statements? (3) What does `valgrind` say when you run the binary? Fix all errors reported by `valgrind` before debugging further. (4) Side note and advice: Try to stick with C++ rather than “Java written in C++”. For example: Use packed multi-dimensional arrays. Do not assign instance members in a constructor body; the initializer list should do that (RAII). Make them `const` if possible.

Comment: `#include "matrix.cpp"` will cause you problems at some point. Better to learn how to compile things properly.

Comment: Suggestion: if the implementation details of your matrix are private, then you don't need to hold a multidimensional anything to simulate an array. If you want to use raw pointers, you can simply allocate a rows*cols chunk of memory and do math when you need to access it.